# Подскажите удобный класс или библиотеку на PHP для работы с почтой через IMAP

Tags: php, классы, библиотеки, email, imap

Для отправки почтовых сообщений есть такие удобные классы как *phpMailer* или *SwiftMailer*. А есть что-либо подобное для чтения почты через *IMAP* на *PHP*?

Задача такая: прочитать все непрочитанные сообщения на ящике, собрать следующую информацию из каждого письма: `uid`, `тема`, `дата`, `от кого`, `кому`, `тело сообщения` - и сохранить в табличку *MySQL*.

Частично свой велосипед я написал уже, но когда дело дошло до разбора текста сообщений на части разделенные `boundary`, а также перекодировке их и парсинге в них этой кодировке, появилось ощущение что кто-нибудь уже давно всё это сделал за меня и где-то лежит готовый для использования удобный *php-класс*.

p.s.: просто хочется сэкономить время если это возможно и не заниматься парсингом текста сообщения.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде в своё время [Fetch](https://github.com/tedious/Fetch) был неплох.

```
$server = new \Fetch\Server('imap.example.com', 993);
$server->setAuthentication('dummy', 'dummy');


$messages = $server->getMessages();
/** @var $message \Fetch\Message */
foreach ($messages as $message) {
    echo "Subject: {$message->getSubject()}\nBody: {$message->getMessageBody()}\n";
}
```

Comment: всё делает тоже самое, но письма внутри которых есть несколько тел сообщений (ответов, пересылок) в разных кодировках не обрабатывает. Всё-таки придется самому додумывать.